# how to recover ubuntu 16.04 after removing python

Tags: 16.04, python, python3

I tried to install python3 using these commands.

```
1. python3 -V
2 sudo apt-get install idle-python3.4
```

But however after installed python3 I just wanted to remove what I installed, so I unstalled python. Now my computer's GUI has been removed. How do I recover Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in to terminal and do `apt install ubuntu-desktop`, that should bring back Unity. You might be missing other packets too though.

Comment: Terminal is not working. Even ctrl + alt + T shortcut isn't working.

Comment: the terminal depends on python (like anything else in life)

Comment: Ctrl-alt-F1 should work